# How to remove focus if user clicks on that tr having css cssselected ?

Tags: jquery, html

In my html table I have two row, first row having no css but second row having cssselected to tr.
I have to remove focus if user clicks on that tr or td with cssselected.

```
 <table id="myTable">           
            <tr>
                <td>
                    cell4
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell5
                </td>
                <td>
                    cell6
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cssselected">
                <td class="cssselected">
                    cell 12
                </td>
                <td class="cssselected">
                    cell8
                </td>
                <td class="cssselected" rowspan="2">
                    cell8
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cssselected">
                <td class="cssselected">
                    cell9
                </td>
                <td class="cssselected">
                    cell10
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to remove focus means removing the `cssselected` from that row (i say this because focus is a term you use with input tags):

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    // If the clicked tr has the class cssselected
    if($(this).hasClass('cssselected')){
        // Remove the class cssselected 
        // from all the descendant td and from the clicked tr
        $('td', this).andSelf().removeClass('cssselected');
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/97HVf/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JQuery solution :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.cssselected').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('cssselected');
    });
});
```